# Render layout from rails plugin to all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am using rails2.3 for my client.I want to render a layout to all of the pages in the application from plugin.How can i made this thing.I need not change any thing in core application.How can i render layout from plugin.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is your layout build? If it's html/css you can add the html code to app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. Add the style.css file to app/assets/stylesheets en connect them.

Comment: Thanks for responding, i have application.html.erb file in rails pplication.I need to add some extra html/css without changing exixting one.I need to add this using plugin.

Comment: Yes, every rails app does have that file. But what's the plugin like, i'm not sure about what you exactly want to do.